# Scrapy - Duplicates filtering and download delays

Tags: scrapy

I was wondering, how Scrapy deals with duplicates when a `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` is specified in the settings. For example, if I add a `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` of 5 seconds, Scrapy will wait 5 seconds between each request. However if Scrapy faces a duplicate request which should be ignored, does Scrapy will wait 5 seconds before the next request ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes scrapy wait 5 second for next request. and if you're set *duplicate_filter=True* then it waiit for 5 second after call next request. no matter if req are duplicate or not scrapy always wait for next 5 second if you're duplicate filter.